# Kendo UI CSV Export

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here is the code I'm using to export Kendo Grid to Excel and for some reason it is not calling the export function. Am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/5wZ3R/9/

```
        $( "#downloadify" ).click(function() {
            alert("Export called");
            toCSV('gridmaster');
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fig it out and here is the output if someone needs to use it.

http://goo.gl/KyzmGZ

Done.

Comment: giving issue in firefox